# Kotlin - How to do Function inside a Function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class I created for animations that is as follows:

```
    class MyAnimations(val view: View) {

fun fadeAnimation() {
    val fadeAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.2f, 1f)

    fadeAnimator.addUpdateListener {
        val value = it.animatedValue as Float
        view.alpha = value
    }

    fadeAnimator.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator(1.4f)
    fadeAnimator.duration = 400


    fun postAnimation() {

        fadeAnimator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
                //empty
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                -- I WANT TO RUN CODE HERE --
            }

            override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
                //empty
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
                //empty
            }
        })
    }

    fadeAnimator.start()
    }
}
```

In my Activities, my goal is to have something like this & run **myfunction()** after the animation is over:

```
    MyAnimations(goPiano).fadeAnimation().postAnimation(myfunction())
```

or like this, and write any code to run when my animation is over:

```
    MyAnimations(goPiano).fadeAnimation().postAnimation() {
            //Block of code here
        }
```

What do I need to add and change in MyAnimations class to allow me to do this? I'm new to Kotlin, and would love to know how to do this in my classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use higher order functions to do that. You don't need a function inside function for that

```
fun fadeAnimation(postAnimCallback: () -> Unit) {
    val fadeAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.2f, 1f)

    fadeAnimator.addUpdateListener {
        val value = it.animatedValue as Float
        view.alpha = value
    }

    fadeAnimator.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator(1.4f)
    fadeAnimator.duration = 400

    fadeAnimator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
            //empty
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
            postAnimCallback()
        }

        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
            //empty
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
            //empty
        }
    })

    fadeAnimator.start()
}
```

Now you can invoke it like

```
MyAnimations(goPiano).fadeAnimation() {
     // post animation code
}
```

or

```
MyAnimations(goPiano).fadeAnimation(::postAnimation)

fun postAnimation() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And how exactly can I do something like MyAnimations(goPiano).fadeAnimation().postAnimation { code } ? I ask this because I want to create functions for preAnimation & postAnimation and have the easy option to choose either in this way.